# MFC treeview control : looking for a foolproof way to deal with data

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, treeview

Maybe I am doing something wrong here. I am using a treeview control , which I populate with data. The data (integers mainly) are transformed to CStrings for that matter. When the user clicks on an item, I can read the CString, but then have to parse it in order to get the data .

Several times I have changed the way the data appears on the screen ,and then everything breaks, and I need to rewrite the parsing function. I wonder if there is a better way to do this...

**EDIT** : The treeview is being populated with items from a std::vector. If I could get the treeview to return an index in the vector instead of a CString , this would fit me perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CTreeCtrl::SetItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6c77ff) to associate an arbitrary data value with a tree item, and [`CTreeCtrl::GetItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/287styts) to retrieve this value. Typically you use `SetItemData` to store a pointer to an object, but in your case you could use this to store the integer values directly.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way you set/get your data in the tree, then you will have to change the way you format and and parse it.

Normally, you should only have 2 functions, the setter and the parser, so it should not be a big issue

I don't think there is a way to make it really faster or cleaner.